# WIndows "start cmd" driving me crazy (setting colors)

Tags: windows, cmd

I have searched high and low for the answer to this, to no avail.
I am on Windows 10.

I have a batch script to launch a bunch of command windows using "start cmd".
When I do that, it is not picking up the text color I have set.
I know how this is "shortcut dependent", and I have tried every way I can
using Properties and Defaults, without success.

It seems I can set MOST of the properties to my liking (Font, Layout), but
not the Text Color.

If I open the window from the Start menu (or Run command), I get my white text.
But if I used "start cmd" it is using different Properties (which I also tried to set)
and text color is some teal/blue color.

However: when I look at the properties for that window, and click text color,
the white box at the far right is highlighted, and when I click it, it shows
(255,255,255) - but that's not what it's using!!

How do I get it do what I want? [without using any 3rd-party apps, if possible]

[image: Below is a screen shot showing this.]

Comment: `cmd /?` - the `/T` switch might be helpful.

Comment: `Start` is for starting programs in _unusual_ ways.

Comment: The plot "sickens" ... in one of these windows with the bluish text, if I type "color" as a command, it turns white! (well I guess that gives me a workaround, but still wonder why it doesn't work right out of the gate).

Comment: Typing `color` without parameters (see `color /?`) resets the color. You start programs _by typing their names_ not by using `start`. Using `Start` is like typing in the _Run_ dialog (Winkey + R). The help for `start` also is the help for when not using `Start`. See `Start /?`.

Comment: There is an interesting program here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41402913/change-font-color-for-batch-file-log/41405637#41405637 about color in command prompts.

Comment: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` this is defaults for Command Prompt, `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` (This has the defaults for **console windows**) and it subkeys by _window title_., `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console` (not interesting).

Comment: @Mark : I use start because I want a whole bunch of windows to open simultaneously (in different directories) and stay open. I use a batch file to do that which saves a lot of time and trouble from doing them manually. I use start cmd /K "cd directoryN & color" and now I get what I want.

Comment: start /? WAS helpful ... I can replace the /K part with /T and /D